# Joining Spark DataFrames on a nearest key condition

Tags: python, performance, dataframe, apache-spark, join

What’s a performant way to do fuzzy joins in PySpark?

I am looking for the community's views on a scalable approach to joining large Spark DataFrames on a nearest key condition. Allow me to illustrate this problem by means of a representative example. Suppose we have the following Spark DataFrame containing events occurring at some point in time:

```
ddf_event = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        [1, 'A'],
        [5, 'A'],
        [10, 'B'],
        [15, 'A'],
        [20, 'B'],
        [25, 'B'],
        [30, 'A']
    ],
    schema=['ts_event', 'event']
)
```

and the following Spark DataFrame containing GPS data measured at some point in time:

```
ddf_gps = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        [2, '(-46.84635, 173.13674)'],
        [4, '(2.50362, 104.34136)'],
        [8, '(-24.20741, 51.80755)'],
        [15, '(-59.07798, -20.49141)'],
        [18, '(-44.34468, -167.90401)'],
        [24, '(-18.84175, 16.68628)'],
        [27, '(20.48501,58.42423)']
    ],
    schema=['ts_gps', 'gps_coordinates']
)
```

which we would like to join to produce the following resulting DataFrame:

```
+--------+-----+------+-----------------------+
|ts_event|event|ts_gps|gps_coordinates        |
+--------+-----+------+-----------------------+
|1       |A    |2     |(-46.84635, 173.13674) |
|5       |A    |4     |(2.50362, 104.34136)   |
|10      |B    |8     |(-24.20741, 51.80755)  |
|15      |A    |15    |(-59.07798, -20.49141) |
|20      |B    |18    |(-44.34468, -167.90401)|
|25      |B    |24    |(-18.84175, 16.68628)  |
|30      |A    |27    |(20.48501,58.42423)    |
+--------+-----+------+-----------------------+
```

effectively finding the nearest GPS data point given the event timestamp and GPS data timestamp.

We thus run into the problem of joining on a nearest key condition, 'nearest' in this case being defined as the smallest absolute difference between timestamps.

I've explored two approaches to achieve this: one based on a filtered binned join (FBJ) and one based on a filtered sorted union (FSU). Both approaches are described below in more detail.

The FBJ approach depends on the parameter `bin_size`, which limits the time window in which a matching GPS timestamp may be found. Increasing the `bin_size` increases the computational load, decreasing it decreases the outcome quality.

Both approaches do not appear to scale linearly with the size of the input DataFrames.

In practice I have to deal with input data consisting of tens of millions of rows, therefore I am currently lost for a viable solution to the problem.

### FBJ approach

The FBJ approach consists of the following steps:

1. Create a `ts_bin` column, binning the `timestamp` columns, implemented by:

```
bin_size = 10
ddf_event = ddf_event.withColumn(
    'ts_bin',
    F.round(F.col('ts_event') / bin_size)
)

ddf_gps = ddf_gps.withColumn(
    'ts_bin',
    F.round(F.col('ts_gps') / bin_size)
)
```

2. Join the DataFrames on the `ts_bin` column, implemented by:

```
ddf = ddf_event.join(ddf_gps, 'ts_bin', 'left_outer')
```

3. Determine the minimum timestamp difference, implemented by:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('ts_event')

ddf = ddf.withColumn(
    'ts_diff',
    F.abs(F.col('ts_gps') - F.col('ts_event'))
)

ddf = ddf.withColumn(
    'min_ts_diff',
    F.min(F.col('ts_diff')).over(window)
)
```

4. Filter and select the relevant rows and columns, implemented by:

```
ddf = (
    ddf
    .where(
        (F.col('ts_diff') == F.col('min_ts_diff')) |
        (F.col('ts_diff').isNull())   
    )
    .select(
        'ts_event',
        'event',
        'ts_gps',
        'gps_coordinates'
    )
)
```

Limit `bin_size` situations:

- `bin_size >> 1` effectively results in a full cross-join
- `bin_size = 1` effectively results in a left-join on `ts_event == ts_gps`

### FSU approach

The FSU approach consists of the following steps:

1. Union the DataFrames, implemented by:

```
def union(df1, df2):
    cols = list(set(df1.columns).union(set(df2.columns)))
    for col in cols:
        if col not in df1.columns:
            df1 = df1.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))
        if col not in df2.columns:
            df2 = df2.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))
    return df1.select(cols).union(df2.select(cols))

ddf_event = ddf_event.withColumn('timestamp', F.col('ts_event'))
ddf_gps = ddf_gps.withColumn('timestamp', F.col('ts_gps'))
ddf = union(ddf_event, ddf_gps)
```

2. Sort the resulting DataFrame and get the adjecent GPS timestamps, implemented by:

```
from sys import maxsize

last_window = Window.orderBy(
    F.col('timestamp').asc()).rowsBetween(-maxsize, 0)
first_window = Window.orderBy(
    F.col('timestamp').asc()).rowsBetween(0, maxsize)

ddf = (
    ddf.withColumn(
        'prev_time',
        F.last(F.col('ts_gps'), ignorenulls=True)
         .over(last_window)
    ).withColumn(
        'prev_coordinates',
        F.last(F.col('gps_coordinates'), ignorenulls=True)
         .over(last_window)
    ).withColumn(
        'next_time',
        F.first(F.col('ts_gps'), ignorenulls=True)
         .over(first_window)
    ).withColumn(
        'next_coordinates',
        F.first(F.col('gps_coordinates'), ignorenulls=True)
         .over(first_window)
    )
)
```

3. Filter and select the relevant rows and columns, implemented by:

```
condition = (F.col('timestamp') - F.col('prev_time')
             < F.col('next_time') - F.col('timestamp'))

ddf = (
    ddf
    .where(F.col('event').isNotNull())
    .withColumn(
        'ts_gps',
        F.when(condition | F.col('next_time').isNull(), F.col('prev_time')).otherwise(F.col('next_time'))
    ).withColumn(
        'gps_coordinates',
        F.when(condition | F.col('next_time').isNull(),
               F.col('prev_coordinates'))
         .otherwise(F.col('next_coordinates'))
    ).select(
        'ts_event',
        'event',
        'ts_gps',
        'gps_coordinates'
    )
)
```

Comment: Does not really fit in with the Spark approach on partitioning.

Comment: what's the spark approach to partitioning?

Comment: @thebluephantom thanks for your response. For my understanding: do you mean to say that there is no efficient way to solve this problem using Spark?

Comment: Het gaat om shuffling van partitions. Er is een bepaalde aanpak ten grondslag van Spark parallelism. Dit us een moeilijk geval

Comment: Tenzij een major key evident in de data

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a **temporal join**.
Check out the time series Spark library Flint (formerly HuoHua, Spark in Chinese):
https://github.com/twosigma/flint

Using this library, for 2 given Time Series DataFrames (the documentation explains these objects), you can perform in PySpark (or Scala Spark):

```
ddf_event = ...
ddf_gps = ...
result = ddf_event.leftJoin(ddf_gps, tolerance = "1day")
```

Your timestamps were not clear, so set tolerance according to your needs.
You can also do 'future joins' if needed.

Check out their Spark Summit presentation for more explanation and examples:
https://youtu.be/g8o5-2lLcvQ

Comment: Thanks for your response! The Flint library does look promising, indeed. Even if it doesn't provide a significant speedup it will at least render more readable code :) I'll have to wait for a bit before I can test it with the actual production volumes, I'll let you know how that turns out.

Comment: @WouterHordijk well how did it turn out?

Comment: Thanks for checking in! We actually never got to test the Flint library due to limitations on installing additional libraries on the target environment. Given that the current implementation worked and a performance increase was not to be expected it was decided the costs did not outweigh the benefits, and we stuck with the existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if any more recent answers to this have come along in spark 3.X developments. I'm aware of [range_join](https://docs.databricks.com/en/optimizations/range-join.html), but this optimizes for ranges or point-in-range joins, not fuzzy temporal joins.

That said, I've had reasonable performance characteristics with a modified filtered binned join (FBJ) similar to the OP. It joins on the bins surrounding the left bin, allowing for a much narrower `bin_size`. It has the added benefit of ensuring matches across bin boundaries but within `bin_size` distance, which I believe is a bug in the OP's FBJ approach.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

bin_size = 5

ddf_event = ddf_event.withColumn(
    'ts_bin_event',
    F.round(F.col('ts_event') / bin_size) * bin_size
)

ddf_gps = ddf_gps.withColumn(
    'ts_bin_gps',
    F.round(F.col('ts_gps') / bin_size) * bin_size
)

ddf = ddf_event.join(
    ddf_gps,
    on=(
        (F.col('ts_bin_event') == F.col('ts_bin_gps')) |
        (F.col('ts_bin_event') == F.col('ts_bin_gps') - bin_size) |
        (F.col('ts_bin_event') == F.col('ts_bin_gps') + bin_size)
    ),
    how='left_outer'
)

# The rest of this is the same as OP
match_window = Window.partitionBy("ts_event")

ddf = ddf.withColumn(
    'ts_diff',
    F.abs(F.col('ts_gps') - F.col('ts_event'))
).withColumn(
    'min_ts_diff',
    F.min(F.col('ts_diff')).over(match_window)
)

ddf = (
    ddf
    .where(
        (F.col('ts_diff') == F.col('min_ts_diff')) |
        (F.col('ts_diff').isNull())   
    )
    .select(
        'ts_event',
        'event',
        'ts_gps',
        'gps_coordinates'
    )
)
```